# Get The value after a trailing slash for url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple url like this

> http://siteurl.com/2014/09/net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps/

How can i get the last value after the trailing slash which is

> net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps

Any ideas. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use split to do this. Like below :

```
str = "http://siteurl.com/2014/09/net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps/"
#=> "http://siteurl.com/2014/09/net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps/" 
a = str.split('/')
#=> ["http:", "", "siteurl.com", "2014", "09", "net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps"] 
a.last
#=> "net-special-report-9ice-father-of-3-successful-entertainer-with-eyes-on-house-of-reps"
```